# Huawei Wallet Kit : Failed to add the pass error

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

I was following the steps in this link to perform wallet Kit codelab:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/codelab/HMSWalletKit/index.html#5

All steps before step 7 were done successfully. I successfuly ran these methods:

HwLoyaltyModelTest.createLoyaltyModel(),

HwLoyaltyInstanceTest.createLoyaltyInstance(),

I also successfully ran these methods to get back the model data and instance for verification:

HwLoyaltyModelTest.getLoyaltyModel(),

HwLoyaltyInstanceTest.getLoyaltyInstance()

(logs are available on request)

However, in step 7, when I accessed the following URL in the browser to try to add the card, I got an error. The URL is:

https://walletpass-dre.cloud.huawei.com/walletkit/consumer/pass/save?jwt=YWxnPVJTQS1PQUVQLCBlbmM9QTEyOEdDTSwga2lkPTEsIHppcD1nemlw.RmhYMU9ETEhpUm5YK3J5WU1ndlhvczFFcUFCb1JZa25wYkN2UGNOZjVuMk05SnVKUkJSYyszU2l3Wit1c1dqeGZwcE1uUGVPTGt2VEUyMXVwN01mTXFIblBmNDJyZmhsVi9mSGFGK1k1R3c3T3ZvOThhbXpMbVo4SEZ1RzBkcS9IS2k5bVIxeU8yQVRSbHZLUkJqMTY3Q3pzUzVUc2J1RTVEY0I3NTErY1d1WjNwRnUyRmdFbmNlem0vTHppbGNnclgrTlVvOWZpVDFvWGJNV2J4cVdKZGpJZTZmT1pLeHlQMlVBcWx0enZYS3YyQThwYVlxUHdpQk9FZG52Q0dWMFhGeERxTHVjRXBSYkpDMkd2dWdINE9XSER0bnJIaFNaNkU0c2hvNm0zTjQyK3BkSUNVemx1QS9MRytpcVVaYmJYaGlQcVNQSGMwclVmbm1GQjJ1bXdoTFRjY09zRWY5b3ZlZUgzSEpGLzdwQWt4cktQMHVQUjJuT3lxTWY1NEJ6VU9NRnRGSnNxZ1dsQzRKb1MxUEFPdzFSZHgyendRSW52SEFrUVRVeElwa2lBVTJtQm1ZbS9xV2N3cGhyVnV5KzcxSit2Z0VadmhJcFA4Z1BlVHFaSjQzL3hxWWtMUWk0UVMxYWxXby9GMDdrYmI4bjJMaldSMzdNazZPaVcwVnQ.NDJDOTY2QTIyMUM5NjA4M0U2QTkzNzI3.H4sIAAAAAAAAAA3LtwHAMAwDsJfUZY9W4f8nJdih3lchlW4oWFr3bFeYjN-WS5mLfcIBTgFMj3eg1vrMG86Id9wymKOGHwVt904TnibWff8vkemg3WeH0vVQoHEaf9BbxfcDLqqFzYgAAAA.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

Here is the screenshot in the browser when I failed:

[image]

There is no other messages or information for this error in the browser.

I appreciate for any feedbacks or hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Please check if your wallet kit is enabled in console
- Please make sure you generated public & private keys correctly
- Please check if you have duplicate instance id. Every Instance Id needs to be unique when you are creating instance

If you need further details here is a nice article about wallet kit : https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201254289105300220&fid=0101187876626530001

Answer (score 1):

when ever your generating the Instance you need to change Instance ID,JWEStr must be encoded.if the JWEStr is not encoded then it wont work follow below link you will get some idea.

https://forums.developer.huawei.com/forumPortal/en/topicview?tid=0201254289105300220&fid=0101187876626530001